# How to pass a unique id stored in database to HTTP request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In my JMeter script, When I save equipment detail using HTTP REQUEST then a unique auto incremented id(Suppose 123) store in database. Then in same script when I am adding Incentive on previously saved equipment then in it's HTTP REQUEST that unique ID(123) is passing. Since that ID is fetching from database so I am unable to get that.

Initially I was thinking to use a COUNTER and start it from a high number which is not stored in database but it didn't work because it requires same ID which generated at the time of savings the equipment.

I created my JMeter script using HTTP(S) TEST SCRIPT RECORDER.

Comment: post your script.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to database you need [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and to define database connection properly, Then you need to add JDBC Element as [JDBC PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor) (or Sampler), and add your select of this id, Query Type: `Select Statement`, Query will be for example `select sequnceName.NEXTVAL from dual` in oracle DB, you can put sequence result in a `Result variable name`,for example `mySequence` and use it later in JSR 223 element:

```
 columnValue = vars.getObject("mySequence").get(0).get("NEXTVAL");
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer...                                                            Is there any way without adding JDBC Connection Configuration?

Comment: If you have an API which will create new sequence and return it in response you can use that

Answer (score 0):

So you can extract the ID generated in the "Equipment Detail" Request/Response and save it in an external .csv file using JSR223 Post processor and use the .csv file for "Incentive" request.

This way you can eliminate database calls and your scripts run only for HTTP Requests with less turnaround time.